# Single atom in a box (lammps)

Tags: lammps

I am beginner in Lammps. How can I create a single atom in the center of a box? (I am totally new) Thanks.

Actualization:

[image]

What is wrong?

Actualization 2.

[image]

Comment: +1, I saw that you have posted your question twice, so please delete the other one. Thank you

Comment: ok! Now, it is deleted.

Answer (score 4):

In your input script you need to define the atomic coordinates, box dimensions, and atom type. For instance, to create a cubic box with a side length of 10 angstroms, you can use the following:

```
# Set atom type and properties
atom_style atomic
atom_modify map array sort 0 0


# Box dimensions
lattice fcc 1.0
region box block 0 1 0 1 0 1 units lattice
create_box 1 box
mass 1 1.00794

# Create the single atom at the center of the box
create_atoms 1 single 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

The atom style is set to atomic, and the `atom_modify` command is used to specify how the atom information is mapped. Next, the box dimensions are defined using the lattice and region commands, creating a cubic box with a lattice constant of 1.0 Angstrom. The `create_box` command creates the simulation box based on the region we have defined. Then the mass of atom type 1 is set to the mass of hydrogen as an example (the mass of hydrogen is approximately 1.00794 AMU). finally, The `create_atoms` command creates a single atom of type 1 at the center of the box. You have to setup other input parameters according to your own purpose.

Comment: I upped the image of this code. Why appears a lot of atoms?

Comment: @eraldcoil, you may check it now, the mass command should be after creating the box, if you still have the error, try to remove the 'atom_modify map array sort 0 0' as it is not necessary in this case. I am sorry I couldn't test that cause I don't have lammps atm.

Comment: Still not works

Comment: Now, it 's work!

Comment: @eraldcoil, Great ~ good luck

Comment: Why  mass 1 1.00794?

Comment: @eraldcoil check the documentation here https://docs.lammps.org/mass.html, mass command can set the mass of the atomic type either with inded or type label, I took hydrogen as an example with a mass of 1.00794. Another example would have been 'mass C 12.01' in which mass command was used with the label 'C' of carbon and a mass of 12 AMU

Comment: @eraldcoil please ask any new questions in new posts, not in comments.